# How to choose an IR receiver?

Tags: sensor, infrared

I am working on a project that requires an IR receiver module to detect particular buttons pressed from a SONY Stereo Remote. I have a regular kind IR receiver that looks like this:

[image]

The problem with this is it can only detect 0v or 5v. Could anyone help me find an IR receiver that will be able to tell me what button was pressed on the remote? A link to an online vendor would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the receiver you already have? Or at least a part number?

Comment: That is (probably) the kind of receiver you need. The IR remote will be sending a series of pulses that you'll decode, the usual way to do that is using a microcontroller, I'm not sure you'll find a programmed chip to do it.

Comment: PeterJ is right. These IR receiver typically operate at 38khz, and will demodulate the signal into a series of pulses. Basically a code for each button. You would have to figure out what protocol is being used for your particular remote, since different manufacturers may have different protocols and then use a microcontroller to decode it.

Comment: The signal isn't amplitude modulated. You get a different digital signal which you have to 'read' depending on what button is pressed, not a different voltage. So that this thing only detects 0V or 5V isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

All IR receivers (that I am aware of anyway) just output a digital stream (all they do is demodulate the carrier frequency and correct for ambient light) - it's up to whatever is connected to the reciever to decode the information. This could be a microcontroller, or a dedicated decoding IC. So you (probably) have right receiver, you just need something suitable to connect to it.
Make sure it uses the same modulation frequency as your remote, although if you are getting output when you press a button then it's probably correct (usually 38kHz, 40kHZ, or similar)

There are various standards used, but the Philips RC5 or RC6 is probably the most common. See [this site](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/index.php) for information on all the different IR protocols.

There are plenty of tutorials and code out there for setting e.g. a PIC or AVR up to decode IR (I have a simple project here based on a PIC16 I used to control a Sky box ages ago, but this is the other way round to what you are trying to do - if you need to control whatever the remote did, you will either need to find the codes for your remote also, for example I needed the [List of Sky Remote Codes](http://www.dusky-control.com/sky-control-codes.shtml), or read the codes into your firmware)